# Passing Variables like facebook

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

i want to know how to send variables like Facebook.

ex: facebook.com/action-man.
here they will show actionman profile put i know how to send like this ex: facebook.com/users.aspx?user=actionman. so i want to know how to just send the username without the query parameter. thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Use mvc routing engine. With MVC it is a must, so you should be already familiar with it.

If not, here you go:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/controllers-and-routing

Comment: @Actionman, routing engine, very similar to that in MVC, can be used the same way with webforms since version 4. For instance: http://codebetter.com/davidhayden/2010/02/28/web-forms-routing-in-asp-net-4/